# How would I correctly use SignalR and SQLTableDependency with Razor Pages in .NET Core 3.1?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages, asp.net-core-signalr, sqldependency

I would say that I'm still fairly new to `SignalR` and `SqlTableDependency`. I've been steadily trying to grasp these topics for the past two weeks, reading every blog post, microsoft doc, or YouTube video that I could find. At first I got `SignalR` alone to work, just by making a sample Razor Pages application and reading the Microsoft documentation: [Get started with ASP.NET Core SignalR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/signalr?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio). That worked just fine for me.

So then I tried using `SqlDependency` and I couldn't even get the `OnChange` event to fire no matter what tutorial I looked up. So I gave up on that and used `SqlTableDependency` instead, looking up any resource on how to use that. My `OnChange` event was then firing like it was supposed to, but then I ran into a few more problems. I'll get into that after I show my code.

Basically, I have a chatting application with chat rooms. I'm trying to make it so whenever a user joins a room, that every other user viewing the room information will automatically see the updated user count from the database without having to refresh the page.

Here's my code so far:

So first, I set `ENABLE_BROKER` in my database and created a new user

```sql
ALTER DATABASE ChattingApp SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE
ALTER DATABASE ChattingApp SET ENABLE_BROKER; 
ALTER DATABASE ChattingApp SET MULTI_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE

CREATE LOGIN [ChattingUser] WITH PASSWORD=N'WhateverPasswordIPutHere', 
            DEFAULT_DATABASE=[ChattingApp], CHECK_EXPIRATION=OFF, 
            CHECK_POLICY=OFF

CREATE USER [ChattingUser] FOR LOGIN [ChattingUser]
WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA=[dbo]

GRANT ALTER TO [ChattingUser]
GRANT CONNECT to [ChattingUser]
GRANT CONTROL to [ChattingUser]
GRANT CREATE CONTRACT to [ChattingUser]
GRANT CREATE MESSAGE TYPE to [ChattingUser]
GRANT CREATE TABLE to [ChattingUser]
GRANT CREATE PROCEDURE to [ChattingUser]
GRANT CREATE QUEUE to [ChattingUser]
GRANT CREATE SERVICE to [ChattingUser]
GRANT EXECUTE to [ChattingUser]
GRANT SELECT to [ChattingUser]
GRANT SUBSCRIBE QUERY NOTIFICATIONS to [ChattingUser]
GRANT VIEW DATABASE STATE to [ChattingUser]
GRANT VIEW DEFINITION to [ChattingUser]
```

My Hub class: `ChatProxy.cs`

```cs
public class ChatProxy : Hub {

}
```

`Startup.cs`

```cs
public class Startup {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration) {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {
            services.TryAddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();

            services.Configure<KestrelServerOptions>(options => {
                options.AllowSynchronousIO = true;
            });

            services.AddControllersWithViews().AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();

            services.AddSession(options => {
                options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);
                options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
            });

            services.AddSignalR();

            services.AddTransient<IChattingController, ChattingController>();
            services.AddTransient<IChatRoomManager, ChatRoomManager>();
            services.AddTransient<IChatServerManager, ChatServerManager>();

            services.AddAntiforgery(o => o.HeaderName = "RequestVerificationToken");

            services.AddMemoryCache();
            services.AddRazorPages();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env) {
            if (env.IsDevelopment()) {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            } else {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseSession();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => {
                endpoints.MapRazorPages();
                endpoints.MapHub<ChatProxy>("/chatHub");
            });
        }
    }
```

My javascript class: `enterroom.js`

```js
"use strict";

var script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = 'https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js';
script.type = 'text/javascript';
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);

var connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder().withUrl("/chatHub").build();

connection.start().then(function () {
    console.log("Custom message: Connection started successfully");
}).catch(function (err) {
    console.log("Custom message: connection.start() threw an error");
    return console.error(err.toString());
});

connection.on("RecieveChatUpdates", function () {
    var url = new URL(window.location.href);
    var params = url.searchParams;
    params.set("handler", "RefreshServerInfo");
    url.search = params.toString();
    var newUrl = url.toString();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: newUrl,
        beforeSend: function (xhr) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader("RequestVerificationToken",
                $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val());
        },
        success: function (response) {
            console.log(response);
        },
        failure: function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    })

    console.log("Custom message: RecieveChatUpdates");
});
```

My database class with the connection strings I'm using: `DatabaseAccess.cs`

```cs
public class DatabaseAccess {
        public string RetrieveConnectionString() {
            return @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=ChattingApp;Persist Security Info=False;Integrated Security=False;User Id=ChattingUser;Password=ThePasswordIUsedToSetUpMyUser";
        }

        public string RetrieveSharedConnectionString() {
            return @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=ChattingApp;Persist Security Info=False;Integrated Security=False;User Id=ChattingUser;Password=ThePasswordIUsedToSetUpMyUser;MultipleActiveResultSets = true;";
        }
    }
```

`NotificationEventArgs.cs`

```cs
public class NotificationEventArgs : EventArgs {
        public RecordChangedEventArgs<ChatServer> ChatServerArgs { get; private set; }

        public NotificationEventArgs (RecordChangedEventArgs<ChatServer> chatServerArgs) {
            this.ChatServerArgs = chatServerArgs;
        }
    }
```

`MessageNotifications.cs`

```cs
public delegate void NotificationEventHandler(ChatServer chatServer, NotificationEventArgs e);
    public class MessageNotifications : IDisposable {
        private static SqlTableDependency<ChatServer> sqlTableDependency;
        private const string TableName = "ChatServer";

        public MessageNotifications(string connectionString) {
            var mapper = new ModelToTableMapper<ChatServer>();
            mapper.AddMapping(cs => cs.ServerNo, "ServerNo")
                  .AddMapping(cs => cs.ServerStarted, "ServerStarted")
                  .AddMapping(cs => cs.CurrentServerOccupancy, "CurrentServerOccupancy");

            sqlTableDependency = new SqlTableDependency<ChatServer>(connectionString, TableName, mapper: mapper);
            sqlTableDependency.OnChanged += HandleOnChanged;
            sqlTableDependency.Start();
        }

        ~MessageNotifications() {
            Dispose();
        }

        public event NotificationEventHandler OnNewMessage;

        // you need to remove your listeners from an event before you destroy a class instance
        private void HandleOnChanged(object sender, RecordChangedEventArgs<ChatServer> e) {
            if (e.ChangeType == ChangeType.Insert ||
                e.ChangeType == ChangeType.Update ||
                e.ChangeType == ChangeType.Delete) {
                OnNewMessage?.Invoke(e.Entity, new NotificationEventArgs(e));
                //sqlTableDependency.OnChanged -= HandleOnChanged;
            }
        }

        private bool disposedValue = false;

        protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing) {
            if (!disposedValue) {
                if (disposing && sqlTableDependency != null) {
                    sqlTableDependency.Stop();
                    sqlTableDependency.Dispose();
                }

                disposedValue = true;
            }
        }
        public void Dispose() {
            Dispose(true);
        }

    }
```

My ViewModel class
`Rooms.cshtml.cs`

```cs
public class RoomsModel : PageModel {
    public string Alert { get; private set; }
        public string Username { get; private set; }
        public List<ChatRoom> Rooms { get; private set; } = new List<ChatRoom>();
        public ChatRoom RoomInfo { get; private set; } = new ChatRoom();
        public ChatServer ServerInfo { get; private set; } = new ChatServer();
        public bool ViewingServers { get; private set; }
        public readonly bool ViewingOwnedChatRooms = false;

        private readonly IChattingController _controller;
        private readonly IHubContext<ChatProxy> _context;
        private readonly MessageNotifications notifications;

        public RoomsModel(IChattingController controller, IHubContext<ChatProxy> context) {
            this._controller = controller;
            this._context = context;
            notifications = new MessageNotifications(new DatabaseAccess().RetrieveConnectionString());
            notifications.OnNewMessage += Rooms_OnEnteredRoom;
        }

        private void Rooms_OnEnteredRoom(ChatServer server, NotificationEventArgs e) {
            _context.Clients.All.SendAsync("RecieveChatUpdates");
        }

        public IActionResult OnGet() {
            Username = HttpContext.Session.GetString("Username");
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Username)) {
                return RedirectToPage("/Account/Login");
            } else {
                ViewingServers = false;

                int index = 0;
                bool viewingOwnedChatRooms = false;
                List<ChatRoom> currentRoomList = new List<ChatRoom>();
                Rooms = _controller.DisplayChatRooms(ref currentRoomList, ref index, viewingOwnedChatRooms, ViewingServers, Username, null, false);

                HttpContext.Session.SetObject("Rooms", Rooms);

                HttpContext.Session.SetObject("ConnectionStarted", false);

                return Page();
            }
        }

        public IActionResult OnPostRefreshServerInfo() {
            ViewInfo();
            return Page(); // I've also tried return new JsonResult(Rooms)
        }

        public IActionResult OnPostViewInfo() {
            ViewInfo();
            return Page();
        }

        private void ViewInfo() {
            Username = HttpContext.Session.GetString("Username");
            ViewingServers = true;

            List<ChatRoom> currentRoomList = new List<ChatRoom>();
            string chatroomName = Request.Query["chatroom"];
            int index = 0;
            Rooms = _controller.DisplayChatRooms(ref currentRoomList, ref index, ViewingOwnedChatRooms, ViewingServers, Username, chatroomName, false);
            Rooms[0].ChatroomDescription = Request.Query["description"];
            Rooms[0].MaxServerOccupancy = Convert.ToInt32(Request.Query["maxoccupancy"]);
            Rooms[0].CurrentUsersInRoom = Convert.ToInt32(Request.Query["usersinroom"]);
            RoomInfo = Rooms[0];

            HttpContext.Session.SetObject("RoomInfo", RoomInfo);
        }
}
```

I've also referenced `enterroom.js` plus all of the other `SignalR` javascript classes in `Rooms.cshtml`

```js
<script src="~/js/signalr/dist/browser/signalr.js"></script>
<script src="~/js/enterroom.js"></script>
```

I'm also using `@Html.AntiForgeryToken()` for my ajax call

Also, my `ChattingController` class that I'm using in `Rooms.cshtml.cs` is not an `MVC Controller`. It's simply just a Business Logic class that I made in which I'm doing my `SqlConnection` and `ExecuteReader()` stuff in. I only have the word `Controller` in the name because I feel as though Its a standard with appending Business Logic class names with `Controller` and `Manager`. Just wanted to clear that up before I go any further.

So with what I have so far, I've run into a couple of issues. Each time I make a change to my database table (basically by running my stored procedure which appends the room user count), the page does not refresh whatsoever. Another thing, is that it will run into an exception on the line: `SqlTableDependency.Start()` in my `MessageNotifications.cs` class

Here's the exception I'm getting:
[Exception Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ED9Xx.png)
[Exception Message With More Details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cTH2y.png)

Somehow, I'm also able to continue after the exception and I get results in my console.

This is with `return Page()`
[RecieveChatUpdates_1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JTHkw.png)

This is with `return new JsonResult(Rooms)`
[RecieveChatUpdates_2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7gKp8.png)

At this point, I have no idea what to do and I feel like I've tried everything. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you share your Rooms.cshtml?